# Which SSIS files should be or not be under version control?

Tags: ssis, gitignore

Which of these SSIS-related files should be put under version control?

```
.database
.dtproj     # yes
.dtsConfig
.dtsx       # yes
.params
.sln        # yes
.user       # no
[Bb]in/     # no
[Oo]bj/     # no
```

Answer (score 0):

- .database # yes

This file, while a "nothing file" doesn't contain anything sensitive and if the project creates it, there's a chance it's needed. Sample contents look like

```
<Database xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500" xmlns:dwd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataWarehouse/Designer/1.0" dwd:design-time-name="259d03a3-ca9d-4501-9f56-bcd17f46a1f7" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <ID>SO_Trash</ID>
  <Name>SO_Trash</Name>
  <CreatedTimestamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</CreatedTimestamp>
  <LastSchemaUpdate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</LastSchemaUpdate>
  <LastProcessed>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</LastProcessed>
  <State>Unprocessed</State>
  <LastUpdate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</LastUpdate>
  <DataSourceImpersonationInfo>
    <ImpersonationMode>Default</ImpersonationMode>
    <ImpersonationInfoSecurity>Unchanged</ImpersonationInfoSecurity>
  </DataSourceImpersonationInfo>
</Database>
```

- .dtsConfig # It depends!

A .dtsConfig is a Package Deployment Model artifact. It provides configuration data for an SSIS package. It's an XML file, contents are driven by what is under configuration.

Why it depends is based on your appetite for potentially adding secrets to your version control system.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
    <DTSConfigurationHeading>
        <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="HOME\bfellows" GeneratedFromPackageName="SO_74797981" GeneratedFromPackageID="{BA78C93E-F2E8-457E-9A73-E8F3A1187266}" GeneratedDate="1/5/2023 10:17:05 AM"/>
    </DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::Variable].Properties[Expression]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>"Test expression is " + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2) + "-" +  (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE())</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

- .params # Yes

The .params file are artifacts from the Project Deployment Model. Every Project deployment model has a "Project.params" file, even if you're not using them. If a package uses Package level parameters, that's just recorded within the package itself.

A sample of the contents, when used, are

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SSIS:Parameters xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">
  <SSIS:Parameter
    SSIS:Name="Year">
    <SSIS:Properties>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="ID">{ea8eac13-d4e4-400c-af86-d15466571e99}</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="CreationName"></SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Description"></SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Required">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Sensitive">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="Value">2021</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property
        SSIS:Name="DataType">9</SSIS:Property>
    </SSIS:Properties>
  </SSIS:Parameter>
</SSIS:Parameters>
```

- .conmgr  # Yes, not listed

A .conmgr is a shared/project level connection manager for SSIS packages in the Project Deployment Model.

- .biml # Yes, not listed

A .biml, Business Intelligence Markup Language, file describes a pattern for SSIS packages. With a good set of Biml Scripts and a meta data repository, I don't actually need the .dtsx files because metadata + Biml => reproducible packages